# Why can my dynamic feature module\class suddenly no longer be found?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I have run into an issue with my .aab built app supporting downloading its one and only dynamic feature. This capability has been working in my app for 2 years now, but all of a sudden I am seeing this error when a user attempts to navigate to the activity in the dynamic feature and the app detects that they need to download the module in which the activity resides:

```
InTouch - 207: Lifecycle: logging uncaught exception in build Build: 1.0000.00272 from Thread: main, exception was: 
Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.reddragon.intouch/com.reddragon.intouch.ui.takeatour.TakeATourActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.reddragon.intouch.ui.takeatour.TakeATourActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.reddragon.intouch- 
Ae8aOmjSevtS5TrlhCSSeA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.reddragon.intouch- 
Ae8aOmjSevtS5TrlhCSSeA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.reddragon.intouch-Ae8aOmjSevtS5TrlhCSSeA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.reddragon.intouch- 
Ae8aOmjSevtS5TrlhCSSeA==/split_config.xxxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories= 
[/data/app/com.reddragon.intouch-Ae8aOmjSevtS5TrlhCSSeA==/lib/arm64, 
/data/app/com.reddragon.intouch-Ae8aOmjSevtS5TrlhCSSeA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, 
/data/app/com.reddragon.intouch- 
Ae8aOmjSevtS5TrlhCSSeA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, 
/data/app/com.reddragon.intouch-Ae8aOmjSevtS5TrlhCSSeA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, 
/data/app/com.reddragon.intouch-Ae8aOmjSevtS5TrlhCSSeA==/split_config.xxxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64- 
v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]] at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2841) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at 
com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I am not sure what to do to go about troubleshooting this - I have examined the .aab file, and it seems all the classes are there just like they always have been.

However I do notice that the path listed above does not include the 'takeatour' .zip file, which is probably the problem. But I don't know what might have changed in the configuration setup to cause this? How does it decide what should be in the 'DexPathList'?

I have verified that nothing has changed in my dynamic features setup, i.e. my 'app' level build.gradle file has this:

```
dynamicFeatures = [':dynamicfeature:features:takeatour']
```

Within my dynamicfeature module, its build.gradle file has this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
}
```

The manifest for the dynamicfeature module is the same as always:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.reddragon.intouch.ui.takeatour">

    <dist:module
        dist:instant="false"
        dist:title="@string/title_takeatour">
        <dist:delivery>
            <dist:on-demand />
        </dist:delivery>
        <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
    </dist:module>
    <application tools:ignore="MissingApplicationIcon">
        <activity
            android:name=".TakeATourActivity"
            android:theme="@style/DialogTheme" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In short - a dynamic feature that has been working for a long time is suddenly no longer working, and it looks like to me it is because the path isn't correct. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could figure out why this suddenly stopped working, but ended up refactoring this section of code to use on-demand download based on the examples [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery/on-demand), rather than the dynamic approach. This is back to working now.